# I'm not sure how to set listing the elements

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

The set is $A_6$ = {x $\epsilon$ B: 50 < xd < 100 for some d $\epsilon$ D} , where $B = \{ 2,3,5,7,11,13,...\} $ and $D = {5,10}.$
Will the list of sets be $\{55,65,85,95\} ,$ or will it be the numbers from $x$ and $d$ that adds up to $xd$ that satisfy the conditions which means $x = \{11,13,17,19\}$ and $d = {5,10}.$

Comment: My edit was for formatting. But I cannot understand what the first line says. And did you mean $D=\{5,10\}$ and $x\in \{11,13,17,19\}$ and $d\in \{5,10\}$?

Comment: Is it $xd$ or is it $x_d$?

Comment: {55,65,85,95} is not a list of sets, it is a set of numbers.

Comment: If you want the set $A_6$ it is $\{7,11,13,17,19\}$.